# Very less vertical transformation

Tags: unity, rigid-body-dynamics, jumping

Im using pretty basic code here

```
charcter.transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Im using rigidbody 2d and I'm creating a platformer. When i press the button the character transforms very little in y axis.

[image: Rigidbody Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using Physics when you have rigidbody?
Try

```
float _jumpForce = 200;
charcter.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0,_jumpForce));
```

Comment: How to stop jumping in air?

Comment: Do you have any script attached to ground?

Comment: I dont have one

Comment: Ok, so do me a favour, either edit your question or ask another question for this, because it will look irrelevant if I edit the same answer

Comment: Ok but before that, I would like to learn game programming from you. Do you have a website?

Comment: I don't have any website though. But you are welcome anytime. Feel free and ask every hurdle you are facing. From this platform you will get chance to get your answer very quick, either from me or anyone else. If still you want then I will give you my Skype.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33166/discussion-between-user75648-and-hamza-hasan).